# ASP.NET MVC Filtering/sorting

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to implement a sort in my application. Everything gets loaded in but when I try to sort it says:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        handler = new MovieHandler();
        handler.MakeMovieList();
        return View("Views/Overview/Movies.cshtml",handler.ShowMovieList());
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SortMovies(SortViewModel sort) {
        
        Console.WriteLine(sort.SortKey);
        Console.WriteLine(sort.SearchValue);
        Console.WriteLine(sort.SortOrder);
        Console.WriteLine("hier" + handler);
        return View("Views/Overview/Movies.cshtml",handler.SortByYearDesc());
    }
}
```

cshtml:

```
 <form 
asp-controller="Movies"
method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="order">Search</button>
    <input type="search" 
        asp-for="SearchValue" 
        id="SearchValue"/>
    <label>Sort items by</label>
        <select id="SortKey" asp-for="SortKey">
                    <option value="Title">Title</option>
                    <option value="Year">Year</option>
        </select>
        <select id="SortOrder" asp-for="SortOrder">
                    <option value="asc">asc</option>
                    <option value="desc">desc</option>
        </select>
```

I receive the sortvalues from the form inside the controller but I don't know how to send back a sorted view.

Comment: There could be multiple causes for this nullreference exception. On which line exactly do you get the exception? Maybe it is the code within your SortByYearDesc that is causing it, or your SortViewModel is not complete? The best thing to do would be debugging it - find the exact line where the exception is happening and find which object is null that shouldn't be.

Comment: It is the handler that is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to initialize your movie handler in the constructor of your controller, instead of initializing it in the Index() call.

The controller is initialized every time you make a request to it. For that reason, your movie handler will be `null` when you access your `post` method, because the instance of the controller that handles the `post` doesn't access your `Index` first. You can find more info on the life cycle of a controller class [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-core-mvc-request-life-cycle/)

Answer (score 0):

use ViewBag or TempData  to send data to view

```
ViewBag.SortKey=sort.SortKey;
....
TempData["SortKey"]=sort.SortKey;
```